# Account Switcher Firebase (like gmail)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am working on web-app using VueJS/Firebase/Node.JS.

I want to create an account switcher like Gmail for example. When you click on your profile you have the Settings/Disconnect but also a Acc switch button and you can see the other account, or add one.
Actually the only way the users have to connect is the classic signInWithEmailAndPassword method.

Since Firebase Client SDK uses a single-user auth model, is it possible ?

The option I was thinking about, is keeping the auth of other accounts in the first user document (with a keychain collection for example) and using custom auth to connect (I did this to create an admin login to users accs) but this does not seems very secure.

Is it feasible by any other means?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store the email and password of the other accounts and when the user clicks on an other profile you do `signOut(auth)` and then you do `signInWithEmailAndPassword (auth, #other users email, #other users password)`

Comment: I was thinking about that but it does not seem secure enough. I'm thinking about storing userIds and name in the localStorage of the browser, and when you log-in create a token on the backEnd. If the backEnd exists you can swap account